# Access C# List inside Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

On the server side I create a list

```
List<object> data = new List<object>();

for (var j = 0; j < items.Count(); j++) 
{ 
    var temp = groups.Where(customfilter); 
    data.Add(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(temp)));
}

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new 
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 

var serializedData = serializer.Serialize(data);
```

Inside Javascript the folowing won't work for anything but primitive types.

```
var localData = @data;
```

This is the error:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Serialize it into JSON and put into template. "What am I missing?" --- the fact, that C# has no idea what is javascript.

Comment: I tried that. It gives me something like this : `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];`

Comment: now what you're missing - is that C# doesn't know **HOW** to serialize `Object`.

Comment: `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();`
`var serializedData = serializer.Serialize(data);`
Won't this do it?

Comment: How would `JavaScriptSerializer` know what properties `Object` has? Why don't you use some more specific types?

Comment: Well I guess thats what I need to do. My objects are all JSON objects. They constitute the List. Do you mind telling me how I can put that info in there?

Comment: where and how do you get the `data` items from?

Comment: `List<object> data = new List<object>();
    for (var j = 0; j < items.Count(); j++)
    {
        var temp = groups.Where(customfilter);
        data.Add(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(temp)));
            
    }`
group is a list of custom type `Group`

Comment: I don't think the use of `List<object>` is the problem. I regularly use a `List<object>` to store anonymous types projected for serialization. The JavaScriptSerializer class calls `GetType()`, determines that the type is `IEnumerable`, and then proceeds to iterate each item, again proceeding to call `GetType()` on each instance in the list. I would look at whether `groups.Where()` is returning any data. I would next look at how you are adding the items to the list, i.e. why are you adding each item as a string prior to serializing the whole list as a string?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the C# code you posted is a Controller action method.

You would need to have your controller method return a JsonResult, and then use a JSON library to deserialize it.

Something like

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public JsonResult MyAction ()
    {
        var data = new List<object>();
        for (var j = 0; j < items.Count(); j++) 
        { 
            var temp = groups.Where(customfilter); 
            data.Add(temp);
        }
        return Json (data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Note how you don't need to serialize every item as you add it to the list.

From the client side, you can call your method and deserialize the result to a list. You can do it like this:

```
$.ajax ({ url:'/My/MyAction'}).done (function (data) {
    var myList = JSON.parse (data);
});
```

Edit:

After some testing, I found that you can access the data by doing:

```
var myList = data;
```

Not sure why, but "data" is sent directly as an array.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all check this link http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Second

```
var temp = groups.Where(customfilter).ToList();
```

If you use where cast it to list or it will be something like Query object *(I dont remember exactly type)
Or if you want to select one object try groups.FirstOrDefault

Third

```
 data.Add(temp);
```

Serializer will do his job to convert it.

Comment: I just tried it. I get the same result `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},‌​{},{}];`  after serializing. Everything is fine until the point where the serialize() method is called.

Comment: Ok tell me You are selecting one item right? Then give me new part of code where you select data and add to list.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I tried the ToList() and there is no change. The problem is I am not able to serialize the JSON.If at all I don't do the Json transformation the serialization happens but again it is flawed and throws syntax errors.

Comment: I am not sure how native serializer works, did you tried json.net ?